# How to install gfortran?

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management

I installed sage on ubuntu but nothing on the command line executes. The relevant portion in the long error message is:

```
ImportError: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error importing ipy_profile_sage - perhaps you should run %upgrade?
WARNING: Loading of ipy_profile_sage failed.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install gfortran` and `sudo apt-get install libgfortran.so.3`

But neither seem to work. I tried the Ubuntu Software Center GUI but it seems broken as it keeps showing the rotating wait prompt even though my net is working. I'm a bit stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can confirm that it is package **libgfortran3** that is needed.
This has been working for me on Ubuntu Lucid (32bit):

`apt-get install libgfortran3`

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

See [this Ubuntu package content search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgfortran.so.3&mode=exactfilename&suite=natty&arch=any) for packages containing `libgfortran.so.3`. I guess you need `libgfortran3` but I don't know sage

Comment: You spoiled it. Using fortran is SUPPOSED to be a punishment.

Comment: I installed the libgfortran3-armel-cross from the website, reinstalled sage and it is showing the same error

Comment: Most likely libgfortran3-armel-cross is the wrong package. Try libgfortran3 (you can use apt-get to install it)

Comment: @con-f-use: why is FORTRAN punishment for you? or if you don't have have constructive answer better don't